# UIButton being displaced after animation completes

Tags: ios, swift

I've been having loads of trouble with this. I'm trying to get 4 buttons to come in from off screen. Initially it works, however, I have a separate button that changes the buttons image afterwards (think trivia game). I just want them to animate like below and be done with it. But they seem to be disappearing and displaying behaviour I cannot account for. Is it bad practice to animate buttons? Do I need to declare the buttons new center origin somehow?

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            ButtonA.center = CGPointMake(ButtonA.center.x - 100, ButtonA.center.y)
            ButtonB.center = CGPointMake(ButtonB.center.x - 100, ButtonB.center.y)
            ButtonC.center = CGPointMake(ButtonC.center.x - 100, ButtonC.center.y)
            ButtonD.center = CGPointMake(ButtonD.center.x - 100, ButtonD.center.y)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
                self.ButtonA.center = CGPointMake(self.ButtonA.center.x + 100, self.ButtonA.center.y)
            })
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                self.ButtonB.center = CGPointMake(self.ButtonB.center.x + 100, self.ButtonB.center.y)
            })
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: {
                self.ButtonC.center = CGPointMake(self.ButtonC.center.x + 100, self.ButtonC.center.y)
            })
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, animations: {
                self.ButtonD.center = CGPointMake(self.ButtonD.center.x + 100, self.ButtonD.center.y)
            })         
   }
```

It's also been really difficult to track down the cause of the issue in the debugger. Even with break points I can't get to the point where they disappear. It takes me to assembly code.

Comment: Did you make these buttons in a storyboard? Is auto layout on? If so, you shouldn't be setting any frames.

Comment: They are made in the storyboard. Autolayout is on. If I comment out the two functions above, all behaviour is great (save for the eye pleasing animations).

Comment: You need to animate you views by changing the constraints, not setting frames. Usually you can do this by changing the constant value of the constraint.

Comment: I'm confused why I would touch constraints here. The animation completes and resides back where it originated from at begin runtime on the storyboard. I guess I'll keep fooling around with it. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: When you change the position of a view by setting frames when auto layout is on, the views will revert to the positions determined by their constraints as soon as the superview needs to redraw. My comment is not a "suggestion", it's the way it has to be done if you're going to use auto layout.